# Find ContentType of current ListItem of Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, csom

Our SharePoint site was setup by an external company.  I need to connect to it and return the ListItems.  I am able to do this but I cannot determine the ContentType of the Documents.

My UnitTest Query returns a ContentTypeID which is not Null but when I attempt to query on that ContentTypeID, the query fails on returning the ContentType.NAME

```
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(sp_site_address);

        List<Business.Agreement> lstRequests = new List<Business.Agreement>();
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(sp_site_address))
        {
            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(username, pwd, domain);
            context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            context.Credentials = nc;

            //get the web
            Web w = context.Web;

            //LOAD LISTS WITH ALL PROPERTIES
            var lists = context.LoadQuery(w.Lists);

            //execute the query
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(requests_list_name);

            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = "<View>"
               + "<Query>"
               + "<Where>"
               + "<IsNotNull>"
               + "  <FieldRef Name='NDMPProvince' />"
               + "</IsNotNull>"
               + "</Where>"
               + "</Query>"
               + "<ViewFields>"
               + "  <FieldRef Name='ID' />"
               + "  <FieldRef Name='NDMP_PSIMSAgreementID' />"
               + "  <FieldRef Name='Title' />"
               + "  <FieldRef Name='NDMPApplicationStatus' />"
               + "  <FieldRef Name='DocumentSetDescription' />"
               + "  <FieldRef Name='NDMPProvince' />"
               + "  <FieldRef Name='NDMP_PSIMSAgreementStatus' />"
               + "  <FieldRef Name='NDMPDocumentType' />"
               + "  <FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' />"
                + "</ViewFields>"
               + "</View>";
            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);

            //Need to specify the exact columns to return
            context.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(
                                            item => item["ID"],
                                            item => item["NDMP_PSIMSAgreementID"],
                                            item => item["Title"],
                                            item => item["NDMPApplicationStatus"],
                                            item => item["DocumentSetDescription"],
                                            item => item["NDMPProvince"],
                                            item => item["NDMP_PSIMSAgreementStatus"],
                                            item => item["NDMPDocumentType"],
                                            item => item["ContentTypeId"]
                                                )
                                            );
            try
            {
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                //Inform the User
                int Count = listItems.Count();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Records found, processing...\n", Count));

                foreach (ListItem oListItem in listItems)
                {
                    //New Business Agreement
                    Business.Agreement Agreement = new Business.Agreement();
                    string DocumentType = ImportFromPortal.Helpers.Document.GetContentType(context, (ContentTypeId)oListItem["ContentTypeId"]);

                }

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\nJob successfully completed..\n"));
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("SharePoint Communication error - Message: {0}\n", ex.Message));
            }
        }

    }


    public static string GetContentType(ClientContext context, ContentTypeId ContentTypeID)
    {            
        string DocumentType = "";

        using (context)
        {
            ContentType ct = context.Web.ContentTypes.GetById(ContentTypeID.ToString());

            context.Load(ct);

            try
            {
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                DocumentType = ct.Name;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("SharePoint Communication error - Message: {0}\n"), ex.Message);
            }

        }
        return DocumentType;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the query is executed against `List`object, the returned `ContentTypeId` property of `ListItem` object contains *content type id value of associated list*.

In that case, to determine content type you need to change `GetContentType` method, for example:

```
public static ContentType GetContentType(List list, ContentTypeId contentTypeId)
{
     var ctx = list.Context;
     var ct = list.ContentTypes.GetById(contentTypeId.StringValue);
     ctx.Load(ct);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     return ct;
}
```

or consider the following method which is more *generic*:

```
public static ContentType ResolveContentType(ContentTypeCollection contentTypes, ContentTypeId contentTypeId)
{
     var ctx = contentTypes.Context;
     var ct = contentTypes.GetById(contentTypeId.StringValue);
     ctx.Load(ct);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     return ct;
}
```

Comment: This did the job, thx!